# Как правильно записать JSON в атрибут HTML-элемента?

Tags: php, html

Преобразую в `PHP` массив в строку JSON:

```
$str = json_encode(['key' => 'value']);
```

Затем преобразованную строку записываю в `data`-атрибут элемента `HTML`-разметки. Получается так:

```
<span data-param = "{"key": "value"}">...</span>
```

Взволнован тем, что внутри описания атрибута присутствуют двойные кавычки, но считывание и обратное преобразование (`json_decode`) при этом происходят нормально, разметка не рушится. Не возникнет ли в дальнейшем проблем с такой разметкой и, если есть возможные проблемы, как их избежать?

Comment: Вообще, по стандарту, ключи и строки в JSON и должны быть в двойных кавычках

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте пару [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php)/[htmlspecialchars_decode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)

```
<div data-json="<?=htmlspecialchars($json)?>"></div>
```

И позже:

```
$data = json_decode(htmlspecialchars_decode($dataJson), true);
```

Где `$dataJson` - содержимое атрибута(переданное через ajax, например)